# Выборка внутри конкретного элемента выборки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Дано:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
    </div>
    <div class="class3">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
    </div>
    <div class="class3">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
    </div>
    <div class="class3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Такая вот структура.

Нужно:
для каждого конкретного элемента class1 выполнить действия с его дочерними элементами class2 и class3 в зависимости от содержимого/любых других параметров этих самых элементов (или, например, выставить индивидуальные таймеры с анимацией).

Вопрос:
как запилить что-то вроде

```
$('.class1').each(){
    alert($('.class2').html()); // взять class2 конкретно в данном элементе class1 (т.е. другие не трогать)
}
```

Comment: [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Вторым параметром](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) в `jQuery()` можно передавать контекст, внутри которого искать:

```
$('.class1').each( function(){
    $('.class2', this).html(); // взять class2 в данном контексте
});
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/sbofen1y/) с вашим html

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($(this).find('.class2').html());
```